# How to create .txt file based on date and time

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, fs

I'm trying to create files based on current time and date inside a scheduler.
Here's what I've tried so far.

```
var logFileNameScheduler = schedule.scheduleJob('*/2 * * * *', function () {
    let date_ob = new Date();
    let date = ("0" + date_ob.getDate()).slice(-2);
    let month = ("0" + (date_ob.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    let year = date_ob.getFullYear();
    let hours = date_ob.getHours();
    let minutes = date_ob.getMinutes();
    var st = 'data';
    logFileName = 'Error log report at : ' + date + "-" + month + "-" + year + " " + hours + ":" + minutes + '.txt';
    fs.writeFile(logFilename, st, (err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        console.log("Successfully Written to File.");
    });


});
```

But it creates corrupted files. I can't open them.

Comment: Depending on the OS, windows won't allow `:` in a filename

Comment: @George thanks. it solved my problem